# Tinyxml2 root setattribute

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml, tinyxml2

I have been trying to set an attribute for the root in an XML doc using tinyxml2.

In tinyxml, the following code

```
TiXmlDocument doc;

TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "ROOT" );


root->SetAttribute("msg","ImFree");
doc.LinkEndChild( root );

TiXmlElement * element = new TiXmlElement( "CHILD" );
TiXmlText * text = new TiXmlText( "Message" );
element->LinkEndChild( text );
root->LinkEndChild( element );


doc.SaveFile( "foo.xml" );
```

generates the following xml file:

```
<ROOT msg="ImFree">
    <CHILD>Message</CHILD> 
</ROOT>
```

However I still have no idea how to set the attribute of the root in tinyxml2. I have the following code:

```
tinyxml2::XMLDocument xml_doc;

tinyxml2::XMLNode * p_root = xml_doc.NewElement("ROOT");
xml_doc.InsertFirstChild(p_root);


tinyxml2::XMLElement * p_element = xml_doc.NewElement("CHILD");
p_element->SetText("Message");
p_root->InsertEndChild(p_element);
```

Which generates :

```
<ROOT>
    <CHILD>Message</CHILD>
</ROOT>
```

Now if I write `p_root->SetText();`, `p_root->SetValue();` or `SetAttribute`, all give an error that `class tinyxml2::XMLNode has no member named SetText` or `SetValue` or `SetAttribute`.

I searched hard to find the answer online, but couldn't find it.

Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your line
`tinyxml2::XMLNode * p_root = xml_doc.NewElement("ROOT");` to `tinyxml2::XMLElement * p_root = xml_doc.NewElement("ROOT");`. XMLNode does not have a `SetAttribute` method, only XMLElement does (http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/tinyxml2_8h_source.html).

Comment: I thought that the root always has to be a XMLNode, was confusing a bit. Thanks.

Comment: What I find confusing is that the root of an XML is always seen as a Node in tinyxml2. So this problem occurs while parsing XML as well. There to get the first child you need to pass it to a `XMLNode`. How do you solve it there?

Comment: XMLNode is an [abstract class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes) which means every XMLNode has to be one of the derived classes as well. There are built in cast methods to discover which derived class a particular XMLNode is (e.g. `ToElement()`, `ToDocument()`, etc.). Also, if this answered your question, please mark it as such.